# Vector of zeros and ones given a condition

Tags: python-3.x

Let x be a numeric vector. In Matlab typing:

```
y=1*(x>0.1)
```

Gives a vector of the same size as x with ones and zeros depending on whether the corresponding element in x satisfies the condition. Is there a similar short hand statement in Python (or common library) to achieve this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = [ int(z > 1) for  z in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with Numpy but I can't think of a standard Python method of doing this without a loop.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
x = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
y = np.array(x > 0.1, dtype=int)
```

will yield an array of `y` that meets your requirements.